# Is "P0Y0M0DT0H0M0.0S" a valid value for a WSRM expires element?

Tags: web-services, xsd, ws-reliablemessaging

Is "P0Y0M0DT0H0M0.0S" a valid value for a WSRM expires element?

Apache CXF appears to use this value as a default.

However, the latest 1.2 WS-RM Oasis spec indicates...

This element, if present, of type xs:duration specifies the duration for the offered Sequence. A value of "PT0S" indicates that the offered Sequence will never expire. Absence of the element indicates an implied value of "PT0S".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are far as XML Schema is concerned, the two strings "P0Y0M0DT0H0M0.0S" and "PT0S" are both lexical representations of the same [duration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration) value (0).